# How does SharePoint online define that a News page is recommended for the user inside the News modern web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, newsfeed

We have added the News modern web part to our modern page, and we chose the "Recommended for Current user" as the News Source, as follow:

[image]

But what are the criteria that make a News page recommended for the current user? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chose the "Recommended for Current user" as the News Source, news web part will display posts which are recommended for the currently logged in user.

Criteria for recommendation:

- News from people the user works with
- News from managers in the chain of people the user works with, mapped against the user's own chain of management and connections
- The user's top 20 followed sites
- The user's frequently visited sites

**Documentation**: [Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-news-web-part-on-a-sharepoint-page-c2dcee50-f5d7-434b-8cb9-a7feefd9f165)

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful reply.. but what does "People the user worked with" exactly means? are those related to the organization structure/chart? or the user which the user have shared files and pages with?

Comment: I think it's both. Your managers and who has the same manager as you. Also, based on the collaboration you do with other users. For example, when you and a colleague attend the same meetings or update the same document, etc.